# Play Youtube in VLC with yt-dlp.exe (no ads) -- context menu in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, vlc, chrome-native-messaging, yt-dlp

I want to preface that I have asked many questions already and have consulted developer.mozilla.org and tried even openAI

This is my first project and please be patient with me.

I have already used a simple bat script to play URLs with the [yt-dlp.exe](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp) program. So I've tested the 'command' so it does work when executed as a following batch

```
@echo off
:link
set "url="
set /p url="link: "
"C:\\Program Files\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\yt-dlp.exe" --get-url -f b "%url%" | "C:\\Program Files\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\vlc.exe" --meta-title "%url%" --fullscreen --no-video-title
```

But the extension I try to write can not send it to the batch script

## What it should do:

A context menu inside a right mouse menu allowing to send an URL from within YouTube site to a batch script. The batch script would execute the 'command' generated in background.js start yt-dlp.exe and pipe the generated stream to VLC.

## What it does

Of course I write here because **it doesn't work**. In the debugger I get an error message after line 12 in background.js --

`let port = browser.runtime.connectNative("vlchost");`

**Error: Attempt to postMessage on disconnected port**

and what is peculiar the system is opening the vlchost.json file (my default application for json is VS Code) in the editor

Here are all the parts of the project

## The registry entries for Native Messaging

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Mozilla\NativeMessagingHosts\vlchost]
@="C:\\Users\\me\\ytdlpvlc\\vlchost.json"
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Mozilla\NativeMessagingHosts\vlchost]
@="C:\\Users\\me\\ytdlpvlc\\vlchost.json"
```

## The manifest

C:\Users\me\ytdlpvlc\manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "YTDLPVLC",
  "version": "0.8",
  "description": "YouTube ytdlp VLC",
  "applications": {
    "gecko": {
      "id": "vlchost@localhost",
      "strict_min_version": "50.0"
    }
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "background.js"
    ],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "permissions": [
    "contextMenus",
    "nativeMessaging",
    "tabs"
  ]
}
```

## The JS background script

It should make the context menu available and send the 'command' with appropriate URL copied from YT to yt-dlp.exe which resides in the same directory as VLC

C:\Users\me\ytdlpvlc\background.js

```
browser.contextMenus.create({
  id: "ytdlpvlc",
  title: "play in VLC",
  contexts: ["link"],
  targetUrlPatterns: ["*://*.youtube.com/watch*"]
});

browser.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener((info, tab) => {
  if (info.menuItemId === "ytdlpvlc") {
    let videoUrl = info.linkUrl;
    let command = `"C:\\Program Files\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\yt-dlp.exe" --get-url -f b "${videoUrl}" | "C:\\Program Files\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\vlc.exe" --meta-title "${videoUrl}" --fullscreen --no-video-title fd://0`;
    let port = browser.runtime.connectNative("vlchost");
    port.postMessage(command);
    port.onMessage.addListener(response => {
      console.log(response);
    });
  }
});
```

## Manifest for the host

C:\Users\me\ytdlpvlc\vlchost.json

```
{
  "name": "yt_dlp_vlc_host",
  "description": "Native messaging host for YT-DLP-VLC extension",
  "path": "C:\\Users\\me\\ytdlpvlc\\vlchost.bat",
  "type": "stdio",
  "allowed_extensions": ["vlchost@localhost"]
}
```

## .bat script

this script should get the 'command' from background.js and execute it so the URL can be passed to yt-dlp.exe and piped to VLC

C:\Users\me\ytdlpvlc\vlchost.bat

```
@echo off
set command=%1
echo Command to execute: %command%
%command%
echo Done
```

Can please someone at least point me in the direction of a solution -- even it this solution would be an complete overhaul of this project. I can imagine that my extension could be resolved in many ways. I just know yt-dlp.exe and am used to it. I have Python installed on my computer if this information is helpful :)

thanks a lot in advance

Comment: In general the Native Messaging host is expected to include a loop to keep the host active. There's a working Python Native Messaging host here https://github.com/guest271314/NativeMessagingHosts/blob/main/nm_python.py.